# How to generate absolute path from physical path in WebAPI Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

In a WebAPI Controller, how to return the absolute or relative path to a file giving that I only know the full physical file path?

I found a lot of information for the opposite using System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPath, but I need the opposite (from physical to absolute/relative).

Is this the best way of doing it?:

`Url.Content("~/" + myFullPath.Replace(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath,""))`

Comment: Is "physical path" points to location inside the app? (you can't really map other path to web-accessible paths)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the value of the [`ApplicationPhysicalPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.hostingenvironment.applicationphysicalpath.aspx) property from the file's physical path.